# Not able to print column names

Tags: php

I am trying to print column names in my table. I am building a program wherein I want to arrange the data in ascending order and descending order by clicking on any of the column names of the table. I am coming across an error thrown by the IDE in the following portion of the code.

Error Msg: "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `address` order by $id $sort");
$col=mysqli_num_fields($data);
echo "<tr>";
for($i=0;$i<$col;$i++)
{
    $field=mysqli_fetch_fields($data);
    echo "<th><a href=\"class.php?fn=$field->name &ord=$sort\">$field->name</a></th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Plz help me correct the code.

Comment: I think you need a comma after $id in your query

Comment: @GarbageCollector Doesn't work, I don't think select statement has a problem.

Comment: @Tony throws an error message, "Warning: mysqli_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given".

Comment: @Tony Using the present statement I used, var_dump($field) does returns lots of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have a MySQL syntax error in your query, to order by two columns you need to have a comma in between as @GarbageCollector mentioned in a comment, so your query becomes:

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `address` order by $id,$sort");
```

Also, you need to have `$field=mysqli_fetch_fields($data);` outside of your for loop since you do not request it for every column, it is the same in every iteration, Moreover, there is no need for `mysqli_num_fields($data)` you can have a code optimization, so your code becomes:

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `address` order by $id $sort");
$col=mysqli_num_fields($data);
echo "<tr>";
$field=mysqli_fetch_fields($data);
foreach ($field as $val) {
echo "<th><a href=\"class.php?fn=$val->name &ord=$sort\">$val->name</a></th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works but the query doesn't have a comma in between $id and $sort.

Comment: I won't be able to upvote you cuz I am short on reputation points but I have marked your answer.

Comment: It is okay @Don'tDownvoteMe. By the way, if we check [MySQL Sorting Doucmentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html), we would find that the correct syntax for sorting using multiple columns is by separating them by a comma. However, maybe the MySQL optimizer assumes the same when it is missed.

Comment: You are right and thanks again man!

Answer (score 1):

First, what do you mean with $id and $sort on this query ?

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `address` order by $id $sort");
```

try this (I didn't use the $sort variable)

```
    $data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from address order by id");
    while($col=mysqli_fetch_object($data)) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<th><a href='class.php?fn=$col->name'>$col->name</a></th>";
         echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Plz read the question properly. What I have given is only the code snippet with the problem. There is much more to the program.